# How can I improve my search in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search email address in my Elasticsearch. E-mail addresses can sometimes contain 'at' instead of @. How can I improve my search so that both (at and @) can be found.

Comment: Can you provide one sample of each?

Comment: I do not have an example. I mean when I search for an email, for example abc@test.com. And it is stored in my Elasticsearc as abc.at.test.com. Then I want it to be found in the search.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to know whether it was `a_at_x.com` or  `a.at.x.com` or any other format. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a custom analyzer defining a synonym token list. [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) you can find more information about it.